# Bootstrap Popover overlay by DataTables JQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, popover

I am working with DataTables JQuery and for each row I have dynamic text.
This datatable shows on Modal.

I am trying to use bootstrap popover but doesn't work right.Its look like overlay by the table.

Half of my popover not appearing.

[image]

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CqjxU/18/) link seems working but in my case (loading remote modal with dynamic datatable doesnt work

**Table**

```
<td class="noteTable">
    <div class="show-popover" data-toggle="popover" title="{{$log->newStatusText}}">
        {{substr(($log->newStatusText),0,50)}}
    </div>
</td>
```

**And Script is**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    'trigger': 'hover',
    'placement': 'left',
});
```

**My datatable script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showLogTable').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 4, "desc" ]],
        "scrollY": 400,
        "destroy": true,
        "pagingType": "simple",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "dom": '<"top"f>t<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
    } );
} ); 
</script>
```

Thanks for advance!

**UPDATE:**

my ugly solution is

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CqjxU/22/) expanding row to bottom (working localhost as expected but on fiddle doesn't look like working)

[image]

**Update 2**

When I set 'container': 'body'  popover goes behind modal! Any idea how to bring front?

[image]

Comment: It is hard to help when your fiddle(s) not is replicating the problem or just introduce new problems leading people to believe the problem is another than you have in mind. I have here made a fiddle that actually correspond to the question -> **https://jsfiddle.net/3by5hz2s/** no problems what so ever. Your problem is something else, something you are not doing right or perhaps messed up CSS - but we cannot know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for modal

**This will help for Modal users**

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
'trigger': 'hover',
'placement': 'left',
'container': '.modal-body'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `container` option to `body` for the popover.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    'trigger': 'hover',
    'placement': 'left',
    'container': 'body'
});
```

Comment: with this solution popover appear under my modal, any idea to bring front?